# How to encode URL string such that it encodes & and spaces

Tags: ios, objective-c, urlencode, nsurl

I have facebook profile image link but when i store  to server the url is getting cut of but here i m getting whole link only after storing m getting half link.

```
NSString *strURL=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://muslim-plus.com/boaster/?aid=%@& fid=%@&fbname=%@&city=%@&country=%@& fbpic=%@",aid,fid,fbName,city,country,fbPhoto];

       NSString* webStringURL = [strURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


    NSURL *requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:webStringURL];
    NSLog(@"FB REgister URL=%@",strURL);



    // set URL
    [request setURL:requestURL];
```

**My url:**[https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xfa1/v/t1.0-1/s100x100/10354686_10150004552801856_220367501106153455_n.jpg?oh=1a43217d27f4692752bbbdf044c9b9b7&oe=57B2CB73&**gda**=1469738559_2a6e31ca3d97d01be6fe6ec25a75a1af](https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xfa1/v/t1.0-1/s100x100/10354686_10150004552801856_220367501106153455_n.jpg?oh=1a43217d27f4692752bbbdf044c9b9b7&oe=57B2CB73&__gda__=1469738559_2a6e31ca3d97d01be6fe6ec25a75a1af)

**after storing to server:**https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xfa1/v/t1.0-1/s100x100/10354686_10150004552801856_220367501106153455_n.jpg?oh=1a43217d27f4692752bbbdf044c9b9b7

**This is getting cut=** &oe=57B2CB73&**gda**=1469738559_2a6e31ca3d97d01be6fe6ec25a75a1af

Comment: show me what you are getting strURL

Comment: i have edited my question..plz check

Comment: i am asking that do nslog strURL and webStringURL and show me that what is coming in these and also nslog requestURL

Comment: m getting same link for fbPhoto for all i have checked  only in database it is getting changed

Comment: as u can check it is not storing from &oe=57B2CB in myurl in server

Comment: Im assuming your server uses MySQL or something, but did you ensure the field has enough size to store such a long string?

Comment: its up to maximum length field

Comment: CouchDeveloper how it is duplicate hv u checked

Comment: Never use stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding.  For the right way to handle this, see: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/WorkingwithURLEncoding/WorkingwithURLEncoding.html